# Issue with applying gradient on imageview of Tableview

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, gradient

Gradient effect is being applied but not exactly on the image

Below is my code:

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: reportCell.reportImageView.bounds.size.width, height: reportCell.reportImageView.bounds.size.height)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor,UIColor.black.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

    reportCell.reportImageView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    reportCell.reportImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(indexPath.row).jpeg")
```

[image]

Comment: For the gradient frame try to use just `reportCell.reportImageView.bounds`.

Comment: @Desdenova already tried getting same result

Comment: @Desdenova thank you for your support, i achieved by making some calculation of frame of gradient layer.